# VBA code to read all the table and paste it in excel with SQL from Navision

Tags: sql, excel, vba, navision

with this code I can take specific value and paste it in specific cell.

```
PA = get_market_setting(market, "PA")
POS = get_market_setting(market, "POS")
NetAmount = get_market_setting(market, "Net Amount")
CostAmount = get_market_setting(market, "Cost Amount")
qty = get_market_setting(market, "Quantity")
transNo = get_market_setting(market, "Transaction No.")
ItemNo = get_market_setting(market, "Item No.")
CustNo = "[Customer No_]"
Itemnr1 = "('80502842')"
Itemnr2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("C1").Value
ECPOS_arr = "(" & get_market_setting("LT", "ECPOS_Arr") & ")"
' SQL query string
  
myquery = "SELECT -SUM(" & NetAmount & ") AS [Result] FROM " & table_TSE & _
" WHERE '" & ItemNo & "' = '" & Itemnr2 & _
"' AND [Date] BETWEEN '" & date_from & "' AND '" & date_to & "'"

' Set Recordset to query set database on SQL string
    Set sourceRs = sourceDb.OpenRecordset(myquery)

'Assign Data to variable from RecordSet'
sourceRs.MoveFirst
NetAmount = sourceRs![Result]
MsgBox myquery
sourceRs.Close
sourceDb.CloseRecordset
'Populate HFB Report file'

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("A1") = NetAmount
```

But how I can take all table_TSE and save it in sheet?

Comment: Try `Sheet1.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset sourceDb.OpenRecordset(table_TSE)`

Comment: In your case how SQL code should look like?

Comment: You don't need SQL just the table name. Did you try it ?

Comment: But this part should be the same?                                                                          
  myquery = "SELECT -SUM(" & NetAmount & ") AS [Result] FROM " & table_TSE & _
" WHERE '" & ItemNo & "' = '" & Itemnr2 & _
"' AND [Date] BETWEEN '" & date_from & "' AND '" & date_to & "'"

Comment: What do you mean by" take all table_TSE and save it in sheet?"  ?. Do you not want all the records and all the fields ?

Comment: So now, with code that I have I take one specific value from whole table, save it as a result and paste in cell, But I want to take all values and all columns from table and put it in excel sheet.

Comment: Because if I write not SUM(" & NetAmount & ") but just NetAmount I still got one random value from this table, but I want to take and paste all column and all values from it

Comment: @Ozzie Take the SUM() out of the query and use `Sheet1.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset sourceRs`